# How to avoid telling the version in dependency with maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, version

I have a project that has 2 modules, the first two work without version, but when I added a new one is asking me for the version.

Why is letting me use the first two without version and is asking for a version in the third one?

**Maven project to create ear**

```
....
<parent>
  <groupId>es.imas.gestresi</groupId>
  <artifactId>gestresi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.imas.gestresi</groupId>
        <artifactId>gestresi-web</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.imas.gestresi</groupId>
        <artifactId>gestresi-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>es.imas.gestresi</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-dialog</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version> <!--Ask for version-->
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not importing version from some dependencyManagement, maybe from the parent pom? Have a look at the effective pom to figure this out.

Comment: check whether you have a `parent` configured in this `pom`

Comment: yes, @JFMeier the effective tell me that is getting the version from the parent. Now I have to see how it does that. Thanks!

Comment: yes @Jobin it has a parent.

Comment: then the Version is getting resolved from parent

Comment: Ok, I think I found what you say! Thanks

Comment: Usual solution is to use ` <version>${project.version}</version>`.